# mongoose correctly start transaction on different route

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, transactions

In my Node.js express application, I try to make a transaction via mongoose. I successfully connect to MongoDB, And try to start a transaction based on that connection via another route in my app. But somehow I cannot get access to the DB instance via

```
const db = mongoose.connection.db; // undefined
const session = db.startSession() // Err : cannot read porperty startSession of undefined 
session.startTransaction();
```

Somewhere I read to use the connection as a DB instance, I retrieve a session but have not method called startTransaction on that

```
const session = mongoose.connection.startSession(); // works
session.startTransaction(); // Err : session.startTransaction is not a function
```

Can anyone explain to me how to correctly start a transaction on mongoose?

thanks in advance

MongoDB version: 4.1.x
mongoose version : 5.4.X

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not so much about starting a transaction as it is to do with how you structure your module. I suggest you create your database connection module as one script, then export a "db" from there where you can hold/update references to the database. Something like this (trivial example):

```
// db module
const state = {
  db: null
};
function connect() {
  state.db = mongoose.createConnection(process.env.NODE_URL);
}
function getConnection() {
  return Promise.resolve(state.db);
}      
module.exports = {
    connect,
    getConnection,
}
```

Then in your module, just get this lazily:

```
let getConnection = require('./db'); // or wherever it is
module.exports = function(params, opts) {
    return getConnection()
        .then(db => db.startSession())
        .then(session => session.startTransaction(/* ... */))
        // ..
}
```

The module is contrived but it might help get you under way.

Comment: I will try this out, but am I missinformed about how nodejs reuses the Same instance of required modules ? What I mean by that is, that I assume that the mongoose instance in my Route has to be the same as where I Connect with the db and the Connection in my mongoose instance is Set ... If that is not the Case, I have to rethink the infrastructure of my Routing system

Comment: this solved it for me now, maybe you can help me once more, by telling me if it is not advisable to use mongoose.connect() and instead use mongoose.createConnection() (like you did). mongoose.connect() automatically initiates mutliple connection and I have a bad feeling about that in regard to transactions

Comment: Nothing inherently bad with `mongoose.connect`, it's just that my version is more flexible, it allows for e.g. Having multiple databases connected or similar things. It is also more explicit in that that you have an explicit connection object, so if you need it elsewhere, you have to plan in advance how to share this.

Comment: By being explicit, you're less likely to make mistakes, like a race condition or similar. And  the people working on the same code don't have to think, everything is spelled out d for them in advance. That includes yourself six months from now - if you do things by "magic" you might forget how it works, by writing code explicitly, many small modules with clear jobs and only those jobs, and then simply compose them all, it's usually easier in the long run. But for that, implicit things don't work. E.g. I might wanna reuse the mongoose connection, but I don't know if you initialized it.

Comment: For a lot of smaller projects, that do not last long or don't have complex setups, using defaults like mongoose default connection is quite ok, oh the other hand. It allows you to move faster and write less code, and anybody familiar with that API will understand the code without problems. So that is also a valid approach.

Comment: Oh wow, and thanks for the upvote, that pushed me over 10000 reputation on stack overflow :)